# Building text-adventure as Console app

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm still quite a noob in coding but highly interested to learn more. As a practise I'm coding a text-adventure as Console application with Visual Studio.

First my little adventure asks name, age, gender and saves them as into Player class object. After these questions, the program asks for special skill. There are 3 different options to choose (explosives etc.). Is the best way to create this in code structure is to create Special skill class with general properties (Power, Intelligence...) and three other separate classes for each specific skill (for example Explosive skilled player has his/her own properties which others don't have) which inherits the Special skill properties and sets them with different values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This sounds like a problem the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would assist to solve.

Depending on how different and complex the skills make the player become, it may be worth looking into other [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Patterns_by_Type).